# List All Google Map Marker Images

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Do you often use image marker from google or copy it to your server?
Where I can get all images list of available markers from google?
The list of images such as :

[image: dd-end]

[image: dd-start]

Comment: Eventually found the complete list of all icons. http://www.visual-case.it/cgi-bin/vc/GMapsIcons.pl The list have been moved here: http://www.lass.it/Web/viewer.aspx?id=4

Comment: This site is mainly for a asp.net web forms control for Google maps but has a great section for marker images: http://en.googlemaps.subgurim.net/Galeria-iconos/Default.aspx?Page=1

Comment: http://kml4earth.appspot.com/icons.html  list many of the icons used in Google Earth & Maps

Comment: https://fusiontables.google.com/DataSource?docid=1BDnT5U1Spyaes0Nj3DXciJKa_tuu7CzNRXWdVA#map:id=3

Comment: https://mapicons.mapsmarker.com/ here have a lot of icons for free

Answer (score 4):

```
var pinIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|00D900",
    null, /* size is determined at runtime */
    null, /* origin is 0,0 */
    null, /* anchor is bottom center of the scaled image */
    new google.maps.Size(12, 18)
);
```