# Google Maps Navigation Symbols

Tags: google-maps, navigation

I'm looking for an exhaustive list of Google Maps navigation markers.

To avoid confusion, I'm **not** looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771891/list-all-google-map-marker-images).

I'm looking for a complete list of navigation markers like Left Turn, Right Turn, Roundabout, Fork Left, Fork Right, Slight Left, Slight Right etc.

I understand that text representation will have some variables like Roundabout **3rd exit**. This can be **1st exit** or **2nd exit** etc. But I'm looking to extract Roundabout from this and leave aside the variable part of this instruction. For this purpose I need a complete list of markers.

I searched a lot, but I could only find markers for places of interest like Bars, Golf Course etc.

Thanks in advance :)

**Edit:** To clarify my requirement even further: Google Maps [API](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=19.178989,72.991127&destination=19.085350,73.017281&sensor=false) contains "html_instructions" tag. I want to assign images to as many different instructions as possible. For this purpose I need to identify an exhaustive list of driving instructions.

Comment: edb is right, this is language (and region) dependent, but so people understand you want a list of the English words/phrases that are not between 'b' tags in the <html_instructions> such as appear [here](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los+Angeles,CA&waypoints=Joplin,MO|Oklahoma+City,OK&sensor=false).

Comment: theon Thank you. I had not realized that meaning of map.

@Xantix Yes you are right. I had not considered text being language dependent. However I have compiled the list of instructions in English that could be helpful to someone in future. Should I post it as an additional answer in this thread?

Comment: take a look at my answer, the output link contains most of the english instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then the complete list (in visual form) can be found in the image below at [this url](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/dir/tt3.png). I couldn't find a list of translations, but this that would be language-depandant anyway.

[image: direction icons]

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @edb in his answer, text is language and region dependent. Since, I'm not needed to handle localization in my project, I have compiled a list of instructions in English. Corresponding direction symbols can be used from @edb's answer.

Direction Commands

- Take the <nth> <left | right>
- Turn <Left | Right> [<at …> | <onto …>]
- Exit Onto <…>
- Take the […] exit towards <…>
- At the roundabout, <continue straight | take the <nth> exit>
- Turn Left to merge onto <…>
- Take the ramp <on the <Left | Right> onto … | to …>
- Merge Onto <…>
- Keep <Left | Right> at the fork [to continue towards …]
- Slight <Left | Right> [onto …]
- Sharp <left | right> at <…>
- Make a U-Turn at <…>

Some instruction that have no associated symbol.

- Continue onto …
- Head <Towards ..., North, South, …>
- Pass by <…>

Hope this is helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope that you are expecting this http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/.

Comment: Hi @Mr.Black, thanks for the quick response. I'm sorry, this is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking to correlate as many driving directions to symbols as possible. I'll put an Edit in my question to clarify my requirement even more.

Comment: SO, you need the driving direction symbols.. Yes, it's also there.. You know that, there are many icons under many categories.

http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/markers/transportation/directions/directions/

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, but this is still not the thing I'm looking for. I'm looking for a list of driving directions that can be received like, slight left, slight right, left at the fork etc. Your effort is appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm...I'll try to give you that what you have expected.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anything official, so I made a quick C# program to extract the key phrases.

The output is [here:](http://pastie.org/4334852)

My code was:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<string,int> phrases = new ConcurrentDictionary<string,int>();

    List<string> citiesOfUS = new List<string>()
    {
        "Chicago,IL",
        "Los+Angeles,CA",


        "Montgomery"      + "," +     "AL",  
        "Juneau"          + "," +     "AK",  
        "Phoenix"         + "," +     "AZ",  
        "Little+Rock"     + "," +     "AR",  
        "Sacramento"      + "," +     "CA",  
        "Denver"          + "," +     "CO",  
        "Hartford"        + "," +     "CT",  
        "Dover"           + "," +     "DE",  
        "Tallahassee"     + "," +     "FL",  
        "Atlanta"         + "," +     "GA",  
        "Honolulu"        + "," +     "HI",  
        "Boise"           + "," +     "ID",  
        "Springfield"     + "," +     "IL",  
        "Indianapolis"    + "," +     "IN",  
        "Des+Moines"      + "," +     "IA",  
        "Topeka"          + "," +     "KS",  
        "Frankfort"       + "," +     "KY",  
        "Baton+Rouge"     + "," +     "LA",  
        "Augusta"         + "," +     "ME",  
        "Annapolis"       + "," +     "MD",  
        "Boston"          + "," +     "MA",  
        "Lansing"         + "," +     "MI",  
        "St.+Paul"        + "," +     "MN",  
        "Jackson"         + "," +     "MS",  
        "Jefferson+City"  + "," +     "MO",  
        "Helena"          + "," +     "MT",  
        "Lincoln"         + "," +     "NE",  
        "Carson+City"     + "," +     "NV",  
        "Concord"         + "," +     "NH",  
        "Trenton"         + "," +     "NJ",  
        "Santa+Fe"        + "," +     "NM",  
        "Albany"          + "," +     "NY",  
        "Raleigh"         + "," +     "NC",  
        "Bismarck"        + "," +     "ND",  
        "Columbus"        + "," +     "OH",  
        "Oklahoma+City"   + "," +     "OK",  
        "Salem"           + "," +     "OR",  
        "Harrisburg"      + "," +     "PA",  
        "Providence"      + "," +     "RI",  
        "Columbia"        + "," +     "SC",  
        "Pierre"          + "," +     "SD",  
        "Nashville"       + "," +     "TN",  
        "Austin"          + "," +     "TX",  
        "Salt+Lake+City"  + "," +     "UT",  
        "Montpelier"      + "," +     "VT",  
        "Richmond"        + "," +     "VA",  
        "Olympia"         + "," +     "WA",  
        "Charleston"      + "," +     "WV",  
        "Madison"         + "," +     "WI",  
        "Cheyenne"        + "," +     "WY"  

    };

    Parallel.ForEach(citiesOfUS, (string origin) =>
    {
        foreach (string destination in citiesOfUS)
        {
            string json = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=" + origin + "&destination=" + destination + "&sensor=false");

            bool shouldExitLoop = false;

            while (!shouldExitLoop)
            {
                int pos1 = json.IndexOf("<html_instructions>");
                if (pos1 == -1) { shouldExitLoop = true; break; }

                int pos2 = json.IndexOf("</html_instructions>");
                if (pos2 == -1) { shouldExitLoop = true; break; }

                string subString = json.Substring(pos1 + 19, pos2 - pos1 - 19);

                json = json.Substring(pos2 + 20);

                int posB1 = subString.IndexOf("&lt;b");

                while (posB1 != -1)
                {
                    int posB2 = subString.IndexOf("&lt;/b");

                    string part1 = subString.Substring(0, posB1);
                    string part2 = subString.Substring(posB2 + 6);

                    subString = part1 + " SYM " + part2;

                    posB1 = subString.IndexOf("&lt;b");
                }

                int posSpace = subString.IndexOf("&gt;");

                while (posSpace != -1)
                {
                    string part1 = subString.Substring(0, posSpace);
                    string part2 = subString.Substring(posSpace + 4);

                    subString = part1 + part2;

                    posSpace = subString.IndexOf("&gt;");
                }

                int posDiv1 = subString.IndexOf("&lt;div");

                while (posDiv1 != -1)
                {
                    int posDiv2 = subString.IndexOf("&lt;/div");

                    string part1 = subString.Substring(0, posDiv1);
                    string part2 = subString.Substring(posDiv2 + 8);

                    subString = part1 + " SYM " + part2;

                    posDiv1 = subString.IndexOf("&lt;div");
                }

                phrases.AddOrUpdate(subString, 1, (key, oldvalue) => oldvalue + 1 );

            }
        }

    });


    string[] lines = phrases.Keys.ToArray();

    Array.Sort(lines);

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Xantix\Desktop\WriteLines.txt", lines);            

    return;
}
```

Basically those are the English phrases you get when trying to go from each Capital city in the U.S. to every other one.

Anything appearing between bold tags were replaced with the word "SYM", things like left, right, street name's, etc.

note: I removed things appearing between div's inside the html_instructions, so things like "partial toll road" and "under construction until SomeDate" are missing.

Feel free to modify my code to add in other cities to the list or add in street address, etc.